# Read JSON file to dataframe

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON with the following structure below into a list in a python variable. I'd like to extract this JSON value as a table. My question is, how can I extract it from the list and how can I change it into a table?

Once I have converted it, I will insert the output into a SQL table.

JSON structure:

```
{
    "Details": [
        {
            "List": [
                {
                    "year": "2018-19",
                    "Title": "PLANTN-OTRWRKS"
                },
                {
                    "year": "2018-19",
                    "Title": "EXTERNAL"
                },
                {
                    "year": "2019-20",
                    "Title": "INTERNAL"
                },
                {
                    "year": "2020-21",
                    "Title": "BIANNUAL"
                },
                {
                    "year": "2022-23",
                    "Title": "WORKS OF 2017-18 AND 2018-19"
                }
            ],
            "Wise": [
                {
                    "Circle": "dgrgr",
                    "ID": "912",
                    "total_seedlings_evaluated": "5270",
                    "Average_height_in_meters": "2.53",
                    "Average_collar_girth_in_cms": "11.32",
                    "Survival_perc": "86.79",
                    "Condition": "Very Good"
                },
                {
                    "Circle": "hgrj",
                    "ID": "4654",
                    "total_seedlings_evaluated": "117206",
                    "Average_height_in_meters": "3.04",
                    "Average_collar_girth_in_cms": "22.61",
                    "Survival_perc": "71.61",
                    "Condition": "Good"
                }
                ]
        }
        ]
}
```

Desired Output: [Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6Ebi.png)

I had used Python and following code:

```
df_table = pd.json_normalize(jsonObj['Details'])
df_table1 = pd.DataFrame(df_table['Wise'],index=df_table.index)
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: So what language are you after a solution in here? You've tagged both [[tag:python]] and [[tag:sql-server]] but given no information about how either are related to the problem in the question. Where are you stuck in solving this problem yourself? What have you tried? Why isn't it working?

Comment: i  had used python and below code..

df_table = pd.json_normalize(jsonObj['Details'])
df_table1 = pd.DataFrame(df_table['Wise'], index=df_table.index)

Comment: [Edit] your question.

Comment: Try `df = pd.json_normalize(json_data, record_path=["Details", "Wise"])`.